# Get the list of item from dictionary values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a property inside the class

```
Public class BranchSettings
{
     public Dictionary<Period, BrancheBO> CompanyBranches;
}
```

The BranchBo looks like this

```
public class BrancheBO
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Branche Rules per Period
        /// </summary>
        private Dictionary<Period, IEnumerable<BrancheRuleOverview>> brancheRuleOverviews;

}
```

I want to access this brancheRuleOverviews by providing a period using linq

```
Var branchSettings = GetSettings(id);//this is being returned by external provider.
```

so `branchSettings` object has `CompanyBranches` populate. I can do a loop over it , is there any way to do it using Linq.

Comment: What is `branchSettings`? Why do you use `Var`(which even doesnt compile as opposed to `var`) to hide the type for us?

Comment: Why do you want a linq-solution at all if you already *have* a working one? Linq will internally do the exact same loops, but hide them away from you, which is rarely a good idea. Anyway getting an entry from a collection (a dictionary is nothing but a list of `KeyValuePair`) is quite easy using `First`, `Single` and `Where`. Have you even searched how to use those methods?

Comment: Where do you provide the `Period`? I see only an `id`, which you don´t mention anywhere.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I don't see from where you get the idea that the OP already has a working solution. I understand the question as "I could do this using a loop, but I wanted to see if there's a way using linq before"

Comment: If you already hava period, why not use `branchSettings.CompanyBranches[myPeriod].brancheRuleOverviews[myPeriod]`? However this assumes `brancheRuleOverwises` to be `public`. No linq at all needed.

Comment: Why is the inner dictionary private?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is a bad design and being done couple of years back, when i was not part of this place, Any ways I created a method to access it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `branchSettings` is an instance of `BranchSettings`. No LINQ needed to access the value:

```
Period searchThisPeriod = ...
IEnumerable<BrancheRuleOverview> desiredResult = Enumerable.Empty<BrancheRuleOverview>();
if(settings.CompanyBranches.ContainsKey(searchThisPeriod))
{
    desiredResult = settings.CompanyBranches[searchThisPeriod].brancheRuleOverviews[searchThisPeriod];
}
```

It's a little bit strange that you need two dictionaries with the same key here. Another thing, your inner dictionary is private so you can't access it in this way. Either make it public or use a property/method to access the value.

Note that `Period` needs to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or you should implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Period>` which you use to initialize the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got you correctly but the following could help you:

```
var brancheRuleOverviews = branchSettings.SelectMany(i => i.CompanyBranches.Values)
                               .Where(i => i.brancheRuleOverviews.ContainsKey(period))
                               .SelectMany(i => i.brancheRuleOverviews[period]);
```

This will give you a list of all `BrancheRuleOverview` where the "second level" `Period` equals `period`, but ignoring the period from the first level and assuming the inner dictionary is NOT private.

Comment: `branchSettings` seems more like `BranchSettings` than `IEnumerable<BranchSettings>` (given that it's obtained through an id)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto As stated I'm not sure what exactly the OP wants, but I tried to get a hint to a solution by an example how you could query such a data-structure...

Answer (score 0):

Made some assumptions about the structure of the various classes and accessibility of members - namely BrancheRuleOverviews needs to be public

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var branchSettings = new BranchSettings();
            var branchOverviews = from bs in branchSettings.CompanyBranches
                from bro in bs.Value.BrancheRuleOverviews
                where bro.Key.PeriodName.Equals(int.Parse(args[0]))
                select bro;
        }
    }


    public class BranchSettings
    {
        public Dictionary<Period, BrancheBO> CompanyBranches;
    }


    public class BrancheBO
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Branche Rules per Period
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<Period, IEnumerable<BrancheRuleOverview>> BrancheRuleOverviews;
    }

    public class Period
    {
        public int PeriodName;
    }

    public class BrancheRuleOverview
    {
    }
}
```